# creating a clickable table

Tags: java, user-interface, click, jtable

I want to create a table where I can click the numbers (1.1, 1.2 etc) under the display tab so that another window will pop up showing the cell details. How should I go about this? I found an example of a table, but it isn't clickable and there are column names whereas mine doesn't have column names. Should I follow this example or is there another way to do it?
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple

[alt text http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/1719/57540815.jpg](http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/1719/57540815.jpg)
[alt text http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/6181/68764231.jpg](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/6181/68764231.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to adapt the techniques in the section "Using Other Editors."  The demo shows a color picker popping up, but your popup window looks simpler than that.